# Convert float64 column to int64 column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a csv which has a column that contains a long "ID" string such as 9075841942209708806(int64). Now, when I read this csv file into a pandas data frame, this number turns into -9.191700e+18(float64).

How can the id of -9.191700e+18(float64) be converted in its original form, i.e. 9075841942209708806(int64)?

Comment: `df = pd.read_csv(file, dtype={'ID':np.int64})`

Comment: Oh, I am sorry for the confusion but if the id column is not labelled and thus only column 1 for example, how would that change the code? I tried df = pd.read_csv(file, dtype={'1':np.int64}) but it didnt work...can you help please?

Comment: What about `df = pd.read_csv(file, dtype={1:np.int64}, header=None)` ?

Comment: It somewhat worked. So, now the issue is that the int values do not match anymore with the original ones. For example: original one is 9075841942209708806 and converted one is 9075800000000000000...what can this be due to?

Comment: Hmmm, is possible working with strings? like `df = pd.read_csv(file, dtype={1:'str'}, header=None)`

Answer (score 2):

To change dtype of column you need to use:

```
 df['ID'] = df['ID'].astype('int64')
```

Documentation here:
[LINK](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html)